# why I am getting nodelist empty when I am trying to get lines by let lines = document.querySelectorAll('.line');

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';

const score = document.querySelector('.score');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const gameArea = document.querySelector('.gameArea');
const gameBoard = document.querySelector('.gameBoard');

let player = { speed: 5, start: false };
let keys = {
  ArrowUp: false,
  ArrowDown: false,
  ArrowLeft: false,
  ArrowRight: false,
};
gameBoard.addEventListener('click', start);
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);

function keyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.key] = true;
  // console.log(keys);
}

function keyUp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.key] = false;
  // console.log(keys);
}

function gamePlay() {
  console.log('game started');
  let car = document.querySelector('.car');
  let carD = car.getBoundingClientRect();
  let road = gameArea.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (player.start) {
    if (keys.ArrowDown && player.y < road.height - carD.height)
      player.y += player.speed;
    if (keys.ArrowUp && player.y > road.height * 0.3) player.y -= player.speed;
    if (keys.ArrowLeft && player.x > 0) player.x -= player.speed;
    if (keys.ArrowRight && player.x < road.width - carD.width)
      player.x += player.speed;

    car.style.top = player.y + 'px';
    car.style.left = player.x + 'px';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(gamePlay);
  }
}

function movesLines() {
  let lines = document.querySelectorAll('.line');
  console.log(lines);
  lines.forEach(function (item) {
    item.y += player.speed;
    item.style.top = item.y + 'rem';
  });
}

function start() {
  if (player.start) return;
  movesLines();
  popup.classList.add('hide');
  player.start = true;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gamePlay);

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let roadLine = document.createElement('div');
    roadLine.setAttribute('class', 'line');
    roadLine.y = i * 15;
    roadLine.style.top = roadLine.y + 'rem';
    gameArea.appendChild(roadLine);
  }


  let car = document.createElement('div');
  car.setAttribute('class', 'car');
  gameArea.appendChild(car);

  player.x = car.offsetLeft;
  player.y = car.offsetTop;

  // console.log('top position' + car.offsetTop);
  // console.log('Left position' + car.offsetLeft);
}
```

```css
/*
SPACING SYSTEM (px)
2 / 4 / 8 / 12 / 16 / 24 / 32 / 48 / 64 / 80 / 96 / 128
 
FONT SIZE SYSTEM (px)
10 / 12 / 14 / 16 / 18 / 20 / 24 / 30 / 36 / 44 / 52 / 62 / 74 / 86 / 98
*/
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.gameBoard {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 2px solid green;

}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 999;
}
 
.gameArea {
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.car {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.enemy {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: white;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gameBoard">
    <div class="score"></div>
    <div class="popup">
      Click or Press any arrow to start!!
    </div>
    <div class="gameArea"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function movesLines() {
  let lines = document.querySelectorAll('.line');
  console.log(lines);
  lines.forEach(function (item) {
    item.y += player.speed;
    item.style.top = item.y + 'rem';
  });
};
```

here this lines is resulting into an empty nodelist, I am not able to rectify why this is happening actually this function is used to move road lines again and again so that it looks that like that car is going ahead...
here this lines is resulting into an empty nodelist, I am not able to rectify why this is happening actually this function is used to move road lines again and again so that it looks that like that car is going ahead...
here this lines is resulting into an empty nodelist, I am not able to rectify why this is happening actually this function is used to move road lines again and again so that it looks that like that car is going ahead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `movesLines` function is executed before you insert the `.line` elements in the DOM, in the `start` function.

```
  movesLines();
  popup.classList.add('hide');
  player.start = true;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gamePlay);

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let roadLine = document.createElement('div');
    roadLine.setAttribute('class', 'line');
    roadLine.y = i * 15;
    roadLine.style.top = roadLine.y + 'rem';
    gameArea.appendChild(roadLine);
  }
```